# Multiple Pages of same Website through QueryString from IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, deployment, request.querystring

I have faced an issue while deploying a web application(asp.net c#, in IIS). What I have is single application for two DBs. So, Through querystring, I am determining the connectionstring in the master page.

My problem,is that I have two links each with separate QSs and when clicked, should lead to the corresponding version of the same application.Which is fine, for now when used one at a time. But when used side by side, they are producing the same DB application, as a replica of the first opened URL (which I guess is based on the server session).

Any suggestion on how to achieve this? Appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I understand. Are you saying that currently you determine the database connection based on which link someone clicks on using Request.QueryString? Also, if I've clicked on 1 link followed by the other then the url for both is the same (and so is the DB connection)?

Comment: Hi. Yes, we determine the db connection through the querystring. And, yes/no for the second. Both links are same, just the querystring for the links are different. Like, http://localhost/mypage.aspx?qs=link1 and http://localhost/mypage.aspx?qs=link2.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the idea at the moment is user will click the link on a page and this will redirect them to another page and on this page create the database connection based on the querystring.

Why not store the link clicked in a session variable, which you can then access on the page you're redirected to and create the DB link from that. If you're using a link button or something like that you could do:

**Main Page**

ASP.NET:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkButton1" Text="Link Button 1" OnClick="lnkMyButton_Clicked" runat="server" />
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkButton2" Text="Link Button 2" OnClick="lnkMyButton_Clicked" runat="server" />
```

C#

```
protected void lnkMyButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     LinkButton lnkButton = (LinkButton)sender;
     Session["LinkID"] = lnkButton.ID;

     Response.Redirect("MyNewPage.aspx"); 
}
```

On your new page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string LinkID = Session["LinkID"];

    if(!String.IsNullorEmpty(LinkID))
    {
        if(LinkID == "lnkButton1") //create connection if first link clicked
        else if(LinkID == "lnkButton2") //create connection if second link is clicked
        else //handle error
    }
    else //handle null or empty string
}
```

I've not tested this, but let me know if it doesn't work.